# connecting mssql database with php (serverside)

Tags: php, sql-server, database-connection

I have space on net4india.com with ms sql. 
my test database is uploaded on it. our team is able to access it from aspx pages. but I'm not able to access it with php code.

```
<?php

echo "hello";

$myServer = "myserver";
$myUser = "imuser";
$myPass = "mypass";
$myDB = "testdb";

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass);
echo "hello2";
if (!$dbhandle)
die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer");


//select a database to work withn
$selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle)
or die("Couldn't open database $myDB");


//declare the SQL statement that will query the database
$query = "SELECT * FROM testtable WHERE REGNO='0705071'";
?>
```

It prints **hello** only.doesnt even prints **hello2**. It doesnt prints any error.

Comment: Instead of returning a generic message use [`mssql_get_last_message()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-get-last-message.php)

Comment: Are you able to connect to database?

Comment: my team is able to connect database using aspx pages.. bt not in php

Comment: Also add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of the script to actually see the error.

Comment: @Crembo not working.

Comment: Do you still get no error? Also, try using PDO: `$dbh = new PDO("dblib:host=$hostdb;dbname=$dbname", $usr, $psw);` and then try to query the database using `$dbh->query("SELECT * FROM testtable WHERE REGNO='0705071'");` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Aksay, based on the code above, you may not be even getting to the database server. Try putting in a fully qualified domain name, ie myserver.mydomain.com or an IP address if appropriate.

You should also check to make sure it's running standard ports, like 1433.  If not, you may need to specify the port in your code in order to make the connection. For more on that, look at the PHP manual page http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php

I would also make sure to implement Jay Blanchard's advice and return the mssql_get_last_message().  Most of the times it just returns "An error has occured" but sometimes you get lucky and get good debugging info.

Hope this helps.